# Should I clean up beast::flat_buffer when I see errors on on_read?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast, beast-websockets

[http_client_async_ssl](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/beast/example/http/client/async-ssl/http_client_async_ssl.cpp)

```
class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
    ...
    beast::flat_buffer buffer_; // (Must persist between reads)
    http::response<http::string_body> res_;
    ...
}

void on_write(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {

  if (ec)
  {
    fail(ec, "write");
    return try_again();    
  }    

  // Receive the HTTP response
  http::async_read(
      stream_, buffer_, res_,
      beast::bind_front_handler(&session::on_read, shared_from_this()));
}

void on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {

  if (ec)
  {
    fail(ec, "read");
    return try_again();  
  }    

  // Step 1: process response
  //
  const auto &body_data = res_.body().data();
  user_parse_data(net::buffers_begin(body_data), net::buffers_end(body_data));
  
  // Step 2: clean up buffer_
  //
  buffer_.consume(buffer_.size()); // clean up buffer_ after finishing reading it

  // Step 3: continue to write
  ...
}
```

In the above implementation, I ONLY clean up the `buffer_` when I finish parsing the data successfully.

**Question**> Should I clean up the `buffer_` when I experience an error on the `on_read` too?

```
void on_read(beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {

  if (ec)
  {
    // clean up buffer_
    buffer_.consume(buffer_.size()); // Should we do the cleanup here too?
    
    fail(ec, "read");
    return try_again();    
  }    

  // Step 1: process response
  //
  const auto &body_data = res_.body().data();
  user_parse_data(net::buffers_begin(body_data), net::buffers_end(body_data));
  
  // Step 2: clean up buffer_
  //
  buffer_.consume(buffer_.size());

  // Step 3: continue to write
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Should we do the cleanup here too?
```

That's asking the wrong question entirely.

One obvious question that comes first is "should we cleanup the read buffer at all".

And the more important question is: what do you do with the connection?

***The buffer *belongs* to the connection, as it represents stream data.***

> The example you link always closes the connection. So the buffer is irrelevant after receiving the response - since the connection becomes irrelevant. Note that the linked example doesn't `consume` on the buffer either.

### Should You Cleanup At All?

You should *not* cleanup after `http::read`!

The reason is that `http::read` **already** consumes any data that was parsed as part of the response message.

Even if you expect to read more messages from the same connection (e.g. HTTP pipelining), you **need** to start the next `http::read` with the same `buffer` since it might already contain (partial) data for the subsequent message.

### What About Errors?

If you have an IO/parse error during HTTP transmissions, I expect in most circumstances the HTTP protocol specification will **require** you to shut down the connection.

There is no "try_again" in HTTP/1. Once you've lost the thread on stream contents, there is no way you can recover to a "known state".

Regardless, I'd always recommend shutting down failed HTTP sessions, because not doing so opens up to corrupted messages and security vulnerabilities.

Comment: My application is written based on the linked example. The basic workflow is to write a query and then read a response and continue to do so.
The reason I call buffer_.consume(..) is that it was called in this example https://github.com/vinniefalco/CppCon2018/blob/master/websocket_session.cpp   (i.e. Line 73) and I incorrectly thought I have to do the same here.

Comment: So far I didn't see issues even if I should not call buffer_.consume(..) and I guess the main reason is that the http::read already consumes all buffered data so the buffer_consume(...) in fact is a no-op(i.e. buffer_.size() == 0). In a follow-up question, when I restart a HTTP connection, should I clean up all residue data within buffer_ by calling buffer_.consume(buffer_.size()).

Comment: Yeah, the other example is using websockets, where `read` actually reads into the buffer. `http::read` reads into a buffer in order to parse a message, indeed consuming the parsed data.

Comment: To the followup, indeed if you start a new connection, you need to start with an empty buffer. That's what I implied with _"The buffer belongs to the connection, as it represents stream data"_

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__flat_buffer.html flat_buffer::clear(Set the size of the readable and writable bytes to zero) flat_buffer::consume(Remove bytes from beginning of the readable bytes) To start a new connection, it seems that flat_buffer::clear is better than flat_buffer::consume which ONLY removes readable bytes.

Comment: I usually organize my code so that the buffer lives with the connection. Starting a new connection automatically gets you a fresh buffer, because they're part of the same object. Mutable state is the root of almost all software bugs.